# Why cant I read whole line along with double using Scanner(System.in)?

Tags: java, string

What actually happens here ? 
Why can't I store a String with spaces in between as name ?
I tried the delimiter thing, but didn't worked. Is there a way that will produce the desired output ?
I know .next() works but we might need to store a string with space. Just curious ...

```
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter number of Students:");    
  double [] scores = new double[input.nextInt()];   
  String [] names=new String[scores.length];

      for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
          System.out.println("Enter the students name: ");
          names[i] = input.nextLine();

          System.out.println("Enter the student scores : ");
          scores[i]=input.nextDouble();
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works ! Thanks for concern guys! :)

```
  for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
      if(input.nextLine().equals("")){
          System.out.println("Enter students name : ");
          names[i] = input.nextLine();
      }
      System.out.println("Enter the student scores : ");
      scores[i]=input.nextDouble();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

when you call `input.nextInt()`, it doesn't consume the new line character on that line, so the following call to `input.nextLine();` will consume the newline, and return the empty string. `nextDouble()` will function properly.

one way to fix this is to call `input.nextLine();` immediately before the for loop to consume the extra new line character

Edit:

```
String [] names=new String[scores.length];
input.nextLine(); //literally add the call right here
      for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how do we do that ? I would be happy to see it working ! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions.
>   A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.

What if you replace the default delimiter with "\n" like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\\\n");
```